# LaTeX Beamer package, change frame title in \againframe

Tags: latex, beamer

Is it possible to change the frame title when using \againframe from the Beamer package, in LaTeX? I would like to have a previous frame displayed, at a specific slide inside the frame, but with a different title this time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
\begin{frame}[label=my_frame]
  \frametitle<1>{Title to be displayed the first time}
  \frametitle<2>{Title to be displayed the second time}
  %Other frame contents
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{my_frame}
```

This is known as using "overlay specifications."  Refer to section 3.10 of the Beamer User Guide (version 3.01).

Comment: I want just to add that you might want to hide second title in the first frame. Then you can use \begin{frame}<1>[label=my_frame] to show only first title.